# What's the use of avl_height/2? And why is assoc_height/2 absent?

Tags: sicstus-prolog

The SICStus Prolog libraries `assoc` and `avl` both provide tree implementations of *association lists*.

While the binary trees used by `library(assoc)` are unbalanced (and thus *can* degrade to linear lists in the worst case), the binary trees used in `library(avl)` *are kept balanced* (using balancing operations upon insertion which utilize additional bookkeeping data).

So with `library(avl)` tree heights are *guaranteed* to be in O(log N)—even in the worst-case. With `library(assoc)`, heights can range from log<sub>2</sub>(N) (best case) to O(log N) (average case) to N (worst case)—depending on the order of insertions.

So why then *does* `library(avl)` offer `avl_height/2` while `library(assoc)` does *not* offer `assoc_height/2`?
(I don't see a use case of `avl_height/2`, but I see a clear one of `assoc_height/2`.)

Comment: And why avl, when there are red black trees?

Comment: @false. Legend has it that AVL trees tend to be faster than RB trees (by some relatively small, but non-negligible amount.)

Comment: Faster for searching, as they are "more balanced". But slower for insertion.

Comment: @false. So it would be good to offer both and clarify when to use which one... (but that's a different subject)

Comment: @repeat The key is to offer both (and any others deemed useful) using the same _interface_ (see my comment to Per's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason these predicates exists respectively do not exist in the SICStus Prolog library is because this is how it was in Quintus Prolog, from which these libraries originated. I do not know why Quintus made this decision.

I agree that `avl_height/2` seems useless whereas `assoc_height/2` might be (marginally) useful.

On "why avl, when there are red black trees?": I do not know, but RB-trees are much trickier to implement, especially at the time when Quintus made the decision to offer AVL but not RB trees.

There are other alternatives than AVL and RB trees these days. I am not aware of any systematic investigation into which dictionary implementation would be "best" for Prolog (or SICStus Prolog).

Comment: Maybe the best dictionary implementation is application-dependent? No reason to provide a single implementation. See e.g. https://logtalk.org/manuals/libraries/dictionaries.html